# Does range improve match operation and which runs first, range or match

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, update, datetime, where

I am using MySQL version 5.6.10

I have a very very large table `large_table` and a relatively small table `small_table`

The `small_table` has only the records of the date `2019-11-20`

There is a column I want to update in `small_table` whose entry is in `large_table`. I have a unique key using which I would find the row and then get the column from `large_table` and update it in `small_table.

I have run the following query

```
update 
    small_table, large_table 
set 
    small_table.start_time = large_table.start_time 
where 
    small_table.uuid = large_table.uuid 
;
```

The above query is taking very very long. I was wondering if I can improve the query by specifying the range of date in `large_table` like

```
update 
    small_table, large_table 
set 
    small_table.start_time = large_table.start_time 
where 
    small_table.uuid = large_table.uuid and
    large_table.time >= '2019-11-20' and large_table.time < '2019-11-21'
;
```

Would the above query improve time of execution ?

Basically what I want to know is **would it make a difference to specify range and match both or the range does not matter when the match is specified**.

Also, as @danblack mentioned in the comment, I would like to add one more question.

I could tell you if I have indexing on `small_table` or `large_table` but I do know what impact it would have in a different case.

So, I would also like to know **how would result be affected if**

1. `large_table` had indexing, but `small_table` didn't
2. `small_table` had indexing, but `large_table` didn't
3. Both `small_table` and `large_table` had indexing
4. Both `small_table` and `large_table` didn't have indexing

Comment: Which indexes are available will make a bit difference. `SHOW CREATE TABLE small_table`; and same for `large_table`. For estimating time, try `EXPLAIN {query}` however it won't work for an `UPDATE` query in 5.6, so rewrite the query as SELECT statement covering the same critiera and rows for the purpose of `EXPLAIN`. Please enter my.cnf configuration in the question - it might help explain why so slow.

Comment: @danblack updated the question

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut - "had indexing" does not tell us anything.  What column or combination of columns were indexed?  What was the `PRIMARY KEY` (which is also an index)?

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated by the `small_table` only containing one range, adding the date adds a hint that could be used in some cases. As worst it will just add a quick condition to an already retrieved row.

'had indexing' really doesn't help, it matters what the index begins with. Indexes can have multiple parts and the order matters significantly. An index with a 'prefix of A' could include A as the entire index.

The indexing on the `small_table` is largely a second consideration as the entire table needs to be scanned.

A `uuid` as a prefix on an index (or primary) key should be considered the minimium on the `large_table`. In this case the small table will be scanned and each uuid will be looked up in big table.

If a `time` is a prefix of a index (or primary key) of the `large_table`, date criteria in the index be searched and matched against the `small_table`. It depends here if the optimizer thinks the date range in the table is bigger or small than the `small_table`. If there is no `uuid` indexes this is the only optimal solution.

If there are no indexes, much slowness will happen, i.e. the `large_table` will be entirely scanned for each element in `small_table`

To check what will be used check:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT small_table.uuid, small_table.time, large_table.uuid, large_table.time
FROM small_table, large_table
WHERE 
    small_table.uuid = large_table.uuid 
    AND large_table.time >= '2019-11-20' and large_table.time < '2019-11-21'
```